# Earliest recorded use of legit as a short form for legitimate

Tags: history

What is the earliest known record of *legit* being used as a short form for *legitimate*?

Example:

> Too legit to quit.

Comment: Isn't that example a bit of an oxymoron? Is the person  or the reason for resigning "too legit" ?

Comment: Ooh, just googled: it's the title of a 1991 album. So why not mention that in the question?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I didn’t know it was the title of an album.

Comment: 1897   National Police Gaz. (U.S.) 26 May 6/1   Bob is envious of Corbett's success as a ‘legit’. It pained him to see Jim strutting through four acts of a real play.

Comment: 1907   Chicago Tribune 30 July 7/2   Meantime the mysterious gazabo who conspired all this..had turned legit.

Comment: @graffe why are you writing an answer in the comments?

Comment: The New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English: J-Z attributes it to British English 1909.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It’s not oxymoronic because MC Hammer has in mind “legit” as something like “extremely skilled,” or “very good.” He’s too good at rapping to stop going. That sort of thing.

Comment: @Casey  The meaning of the phrase, isolated, without context and without knowing it was the title of an album, is not at all apparent but thanks for clearing up that small mystery :))